# Replace certain record with the value from other table

Tags: mysql

I want to replace a record `name` for certain `id` with the value from other table (with the same ID).

Let me explain it like this:

`TABLE1:`

There is a record with the `name` set to `xxyyzz123` and its `id` equals `24`,

Now I want to replace the `name` in `TABLE1` for the record with `id` = `24` with the `name` for `id` = `24` from `TABLE2`, so if `name` in the `TABLE2` will be `xyyzzz321` it should be now the same in the `TABLE1` (after the update query).

Could this be done in the MySQL? Could you give me some tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `update query with inner join between table1 and table2`, which will match the id from both the table
with where condition.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET    Table1.name = Table2.name,    
FROM   Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON     Table1.id = Table2.id
WHERE  Table1.id = 24
```

Answer (score 2):

TRY

```
UPDATE table1 t1 , table2 t2
SET t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

This will replace all `t1.name` with `t2.name` where id are similar in table  t1 and t2

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
SET t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.id = 24
```